# converting the convolution code matlab to opencv in cpp

Tags: c++, opencv, gradient, convolution

Here is my horizontal gradient results.The left one is opencv result and the other one is matlab result

[image]

I am trying to do horizontal and vertical gradient which H =[1,-1] and V=[1;-1]

```
    Mat H_gradient,G_Filter1,kernel,V_gradient;

    Mat kernelH(1, 2, CV_32F);  
    kernelH.at<float>(0,0) = 1.0f;
    kernelH.at<float>(0,1) = -1.0f;


    Mat kernelV(2, 1, CV_32F);
    kernelV.at<float>(0,0) = 1.0f;
    kernelV.at<float>(1,0) = -1.0f;

    cvtColor( image, image, CV_RGB2GRAY );

    filter2D( image, H_gradient, -1 ,kernelH , Point( -1, -1 ), 0, BORDER_DEFAULT ); 
    filter2D( image, V_gradient, -1 ,kernelV , Point( -1, -1 ), 0, BORDER_DEFAULT );
```

But still not match with my matlab code  results. I dont know why?

My matlab code for gradients

```
image=double(image);
% horizontal and vertical gradient
H=[1 -1];
V=[1;-1];

H_Gradient=conv2(image,H,'same'); 
V_Gradient=conv2(image,V,'same');
```

Comment: Can you show us the difference in an example image?

Comment: I add the image left one is opencv result @ypnos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try do

```
cvtColor( image, image, **CV_BGR2GRAY** );
```

instead of

```
cvtColor( image, image, **CV_RGB2GRAY** );
```

If you are using the default imread parameters, OpenCv use BGR color format instead of RGB as default!

Comment: I changed to *CV_BGR2GRAY  but still  my opencv and matlab result not same

Answer (score 0):

Do the same that you did in Matlab, first convert your image to double.

```
image.convertTo(image, CV_32F);
```

Now I got the same result in OpenCv and Matlab.

Comment: I changed to  kernel H=[1 -1] to H=[-1  1]  and it works now ı dont now why. thanks for advises @André